# "active continuous job can't be executed manually" when provisioning Databricks Job in Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-workflows

I'm trying to provision and run a job 'forever' in Databricks via Terraform, but get an error on the first run of Terraform apply.  Just continuous job itself appears to get going, but Terraform itself fails (which has downstream effects).  The job itself could run forever, but when and if it fails, should be restarted.

I think this should be the relevant Terraform code:

```
resource  "databricks_notebook" "simulated_device"  {
  path     = "/simulated-data/simulated_device.py"
  language = "PYTHON"
  source   = "../simulated-data/device.py"
}

resource "databricks_job" "simulated_data" {
  name                = "Generate Simulated Data"
  existing_cluster_id = databricks_cluster.telemetry_cluster.cluster_id
  always_running      = true
  notebook_task {
    notebook_path = databricks_notebook.simulated_device.path
  }
  continuous {
    pause_status      = "UNPAUSED"
  }
}
```

I consistently get `Error: cannot create job: cannot start job run: An active continuous job can't be executed manually. A new run can be triggered by cancelling the existing run.`  The error references the `databricks_job` block from the code sample above.

It seems like I'm somehow telling Databricks to start the job after it's already continuous.  This could possibly be a bug of some sort, but it seems more likely that I'm misunderstanding something.

I'm using version 1.14.3 of the Databricks Terraform provider.

Comment: Thanks for raising this Chuck. I believe this is an actual issue in the Databricks Terraform provider implementation which doesn't properly handle restarting continuous jobs. I'm currently working on a fix. The upstream issue is tracked here: https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/2130

Comment: Sorry, on closer read, I think this is not related to the above github issue specifically, but it is still an issue that I am working on.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this? I am not able to deploy neither 'continuous {}', nor 'continuous=true',  nor 'always_running=true'. Neither at job level, nor task level.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you need to use either `always_running` or `continuos`, although I would recommend to use `continuous` as it's a part of Jobs API, while `always_running` was an attempt to provide similar funcitonality from the terraform provider itself.  Most probably you'll able to use both in the future